# Primefaces SelectOneMenu not rendering properly with text

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying a userform with primefaces 3.5, all the components are working fine except selectonemenu, which not render correctly.

Its text field is not showing on selection of any drop down field.

i can't post image as i don't have that much reputation

**Code**

```
<p:panelGrid id="jobsGrid" columns="2" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;text-align:left;">
  <f:facet name="header"> ----- Quick Job Posting -----</f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="OLF Number " />
    <p:inputText value="#{jobs.jobDetail.OLF_No}" />
    <h:outputText value="RRF Number " />
    <p:inputText  value="#{jobs.jobDetail.RRF_No}" />
    <h:outputText value="OLF Status " />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{jobs.jobDetail.OLF_Status}" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;height:5px;font-size:10px">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="---- Select ----" itemValue="" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approved" itemValue="Approved" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pending Approval" itemValue="Pending Approval" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="New" itemValue="New" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputText value="RRF Type " />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{jobs.jobDetail.RRF_type}" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;height:5px;font-size:10px">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="---- Select ----" itemValue="" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Growth" itemValue="Growth" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Replacement" itemValue="Replacement" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

How can i fix this ?

Comment: post you image at http://imageshack.us/ and provide link i will upload image

Comment: thanks @jubinPatel, i updated with image link

Comment: It was actually not me, it was @jubinPatel, I just approved the edit he suggested. Thanks jubinPatel! :)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this this problem by adding following CSS to my page:

```
.ui-selectonemenu label.ui-selectonemenu-label{
   width:100% !important;
}
```

I also have fixed widths on my selectonemenus.
Hope this helps in your case also. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem in Primefaces 3.5. I had the exact same issue, and downgrading to 3.4 solved it.

As a data point, it is worth noting that the rendering problem only existed when I navigated to the page through a p:remoteCommand. Normal action-based navigation works correctly, at least for me.

Comment: One other interesting bit of information is that this appears to only be a problem in Google Chrome. I just tried in Firefox and the problem disappeared there too.

Comment: Still a problem in Primefaces 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can post your code some here, or if not try checking BalusC http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html

If you see that your bean annotations are correct, try using primefaces 3.4 or lower versions.

Comment: i guess, primefaces libraries will help :), just its not rendering, dunno why :(